# What causes MS Visual Studio to be unable to recognize build errors?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

In `Visual Studio Express 2010`, I can usually only build a program once and then to make any changes I have to paste my code into a new project. It will say that the build was successful, but then I try to run it and get an error message saying,

> "This project is out of date-- would you like to build it?"

and I click yes and I get another error message saying that there were build errors and I have to continue from the last successful build. *Sometimes* instead of running the last successful build I get an error message saying,

> "Unable to open [directory to program]. The system cannot find the
>   file specified."

I usually use `Visual Express 2012` for this reason but even then it happens every now and then, seemingly at random. Once the issue begins there is no apparent way to fix it (rebuilding and restarting Visual Studio both have the same result). In `Visual Studio Pro 2012` this also seems to happen.

EDIT: This is in the output box of the one in front of me (2010 edition)

```
1>------ Build started: Project: Lab01, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  Lab01.cpp
1>c:\program files (x86)\reference assemblies\microsoft\framework\.netframework\v4.0\system.core.dll : warning C4945: 'ExtensionAttribute' : cannot import symbol from 'c:\program files (x86)\reference assemblies\microsoft\framework\.netframework\v4.0\system.core.dll': as 'System::Runtime::CompilerServices::ExtensionAttribute' has already been imported from another assembly 'mscorlib'
1>          c:\windows\microsoft.net\framework\v4.0.30319\mscorlib.dll : see declaration of 'System::Runtime::CompilerServices::ExtensionAttribute'
1>          first seen type is used; re-order imported assemblies to use the current type
1>          This diagnostic occurred while importing type 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ExtensionAttribute' from assembly 'System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.
1>Lab01.cpp(28): error C2664: 'std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits>::get(_Elem &)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'char [101]' to 'char &'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

I guess it says the error in there but it tells me "build succeeded" for some reason...

Comment: Two things that came to my mind: 1 - do you have writing privileges for the project and directories you're trying to use? 2 - Are you using CMake to build the project within VS?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: `continue from the last successful build` - And errors show up in the `View->Error List`?  (Or they don't?)  Also, I assume you're hitting "build" before "run" and checking `Error List` before hitting run?  A "rebuild" must give some other error than "project is out of date".  Also check `Output` window after build it's more detailed.

Comment: Writing privileges, I'm not sure what you mean, I just start a "blank project" and start a source code (this is for school). I'm not familiar with CMAKE. EDIT: Oh, yeah there are clues here I guess..

Comment: egur is talking about OS level file access to your user account(s).

Comment: Is there an equivalent of view --> error list in the 2010 edition? I don't have a corrupted 2012 project in front of me atm. But in the 2010 one in front of me, no errors show up in the bottom box. And yes I hit build first.

Comment: I use an administrator account on Windows, yeah.

Comment: 1) Admin doesn't always mean you have file access rights.  2) Every version of Visual Studio I've ever seen has `View->Output` and `View->Error List`.  (ie: go to the bar at top of screen.  click `View`.  then click `Error List` or click `Output`.  A new (probably docked) window should appear.  Both of these are your communication channels with the compiler.  If they are not present you have no hope of getting any kind of useful work done in Visual Studio.  (unless maybe you run everything from command line without UI)

Comment: Yeah I noticed that for the one in question there is a lot of stuff in the error box but I don't know what it means. I edited my original question with it.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how to find and analyze errors reported by Visual Studio:

`continue from the last successful build` - Click **NO** (almost always).  Errors should show up in the `View->Error List`.  When confused, always check `View->Output` window after a build, it's a lot of the same info but more detailed.

`rebuilding ... same result` - A full rebuild should give some other error than `project is out of date`.

`Lab01.cpp(28): error C2664:` - Line 28 and 3 lines up and down of Lab01.cpp would be helpful.

Looks like you're doing something with std:: streams that isn't correct, but I don't know what without seeing the code.  **This should be in the Error List**

`warning C4945:` - This occurs because you're using a mix of .net 4.0 and 4.5 and (possibly) a mix of clr and non-clr code within a single project.  Recreating from a new CLR project which has chosen the correct .Net library version everywhere may remove this warning.  (`ExtensionAttribute` got moved during the 4.0 to 4.5 upgrade)

This is just a warning, so shouldn't matter.